# Check if widget is active

Tags: widgets

I have two custom widgets a Search_Widget_Page which is created with the following code;

```
class Search_Widget_Page extends WP_Widget {
    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'Search_Widget_Page',
            __('Search Form - Pages', 'text_domain'),
            array( 'description' => __( 'Add a search form to a page, there must not be another search form in the side bar.', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }
```

I then have another similar widget that can display in the sidebar, however, I do no want it to display if the widget above is being used on the page. I have tried the following code to no avail;

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

if( is_active_widget( 'Search_Widget_Page' ) ) { // check if search widget is used

   Do not display this widget

} else {

   Display this widget

}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget), you may add some additional parameters to `is_active_widget()` to make it work. So try this one:

```php
if ( is_active_widget(false, false, 'Search_Widget_Page', true) ) { // check if search widget is used

   // Do not display this widget

} else {

   // Display this widget

}
```